# How do I export as picture from Enterprise Architect without a frame or diagram name?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I have some diagrams in Enterprise Architect that I want to import to MS Word.

How can I get rid of the border around the diagram and the diagram name when exporting it to picture? How can this be disabled?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, combining `enterprise` and `architect` doesn't mean you're talking about the tool by Sparx Systems.  There is a separate tag for that, `enterprise-architect`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Oh I just found it by accident.
Just for reference, as I saw people searching for this from time to time on the net:

```
Tools > Options > Diagram > Diagram Frames > deselect all checkboxes
```

Comment: In the Ribbon GUI (Enterprise Architect 13), this is located under START > Workspace > Preferences > Diagram > Diagram Frames