# How do I export as picture from EA13 without a frame or diagram name?

Tags: enterprise-architect

this is the answer to the same old question
[How do I export as picture from Enterprise Architect without a frame or diagram name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913053/how-do-i-export-as-picture-from-enterprise-architect-without-a-frame-or-diagram)

But EA13 has a complete different UI, and I cannot find anything anymore
it´s to despair

thanks for answers

Comment: Try the search field from the start menu. That astonishingly seems to work quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type "Options" in the Start/Search field it shows "Preferences" (besides Options which is only a part of the former options). That "Preferences" now has the former Options.

(May the inventor of those ribbons be strangled with one of them.)

Comment: thx, great, I searched this Start/Search field, I knew there is one, but I couldn´t remember where it is.